# code HPE_INVALID_METHOD Node js Hapi js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make GET request to my API endpoint and when I do the request from another server to the API I see this strange error (on the API):

```
 170125/230803.439, [log,connection,client,error] data: {"bytesParsed":0,"code":"HPE_INVALID_METHOD"}
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 15):

I am sorry I did request on `https://` I should have done it on `http://` instead

Comment: Spent an hour to figure out what is happening. Thanks. Helpful :)