# What could cause a HPE_INVALID_METHOD error using fastify and nunjucks?

Tags: nunjucks, fastify

I disabled all plugins on the server except point-of-view.

```
fastify.register(require('point-of-view'), {
  engine: {
    nunjucks: require('nunjucks')
  },
  templates: 'server/views',
  includeViewExtension: true
})
```

The handler is calling the view function.

```
reply.view('/v1/main', {
  nonce: nanoid(1),
  token: nanoid(1)
})
```

The complete error message is:

```
{"level":50,"time":1547208496144,"msg":"client error","pid":16013,"hostname":"jer-ryzentwo","err":{"type":"Error","message":"Parse Error","stack":"Error: Parse Error","bytesParsed":0,"code":"HPE_INVALID_METHOD","rawPacket":{"type":"Buffer","data":[22,3,1,2,0,1,0,1,105,3,3,167,247,206,59,236,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}},"v":1}

{"level":50,"time":1547208496145,"msg":"client error","pid":16013,"hostname":"jer-ryzentwo","err":{"type":"Error","message":"Parse Error","stack":"Error: Parse Error","bytesParsed":0,"code":"HPE_INVALID_METHOD","rawPacket":{"type":"Buffer","data":[10,0,1,0,2,2,20]}},"v":1}
```

I cannot pinpoint the source of this issue.
Any idea what and why a HPE_INVALID_METHOD error is being generated?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863369/code-hpe-invalid-method-node-js-hapi-js)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No I found it but everything is served through http, no https is present in any code of this project. It happens only when serving with `view`. If I open the file and stream it I don't have that error.

Comment: Do you have the same issue with another template or passed data? Try to update Node.js :)

Comment: I woke up yesterday and the error was gone... This happens to me quite a lot. I should probably reformat  or something. Thanks for your comment anyway :)